# Joda Time cannot subtract one hour

Tags: java, android, date, jodatime

In my android program, I have a spinner that allows the user to select different times. Each selection is processed with Joda time to subtract the minutes. It works fine for minutes 0 to 59 and 61 and greater. However, when 60 minutes is subtracted, the time is not updated, and the original time is shown.

How do I get Joda time to subtract 60 minutes?

Spinner:

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {



            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                    long id1) {


                    String mins =     parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                    int intmins=0;

                    // process user's selection of alert time
                    if(mins.equals("5 minutes")){intmins = 5;}
                    if(mins.equals("10 minutes")){intmins = 10;}
                    if(mins.equals("20 minutes")){intmins = 20;}
                    if(mins.equals("30 minutes")){intmins = 30;}
                    if(mins.equals("40 minutes")){intmins = 40;}
                    if(mins.equals("50 minutes")){intmins = 50;}
                      if(mins.equals("60 minutes")){intmins = 60;}
                        if(mins.equals("120 minutes")){intmins = 120;}

                    String stringMinutes=""+intmins;
                    setAlarm(intmins, stringMinutes);



                } else {



            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
                mLocationDisplay.setText(" " + location);
            }
        }




            public void setAlarm(int intmins, String mins) {
                // based alarm time on start time of event. TODO get info from database.

                String currentDate;
                SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                Date date1 = null;
                DateTime dt;
                currentDate = eventdate + " " + startTimeMilitary;// startTimeMilitary;

            try {
                    date1 = myFormat.parse(currentDate);


                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                dt = new DateTime(date1);
                long dateInMillis = dt.getMillis();
                String sDateInMillis = Long.toString(dateInMillis);

                // subtract the selected time from the event's start time

                String   newAlertTime = subtractTime(dt, intmins);

                 newAlertTime = subtractTime(dt, intmins);
//......}



public String subtractTime(DateTime dt, int minusTime) {

                DateTime greaterDate;


                     greaterDate = dt.minusMinutes(minusTime);



                // newAlertTime is in UTC format
                String newAlertTime = greaterDate.toString();

                long alertInMillis = greaterDate.getMillis();
                String sAlertInMillis = Long.toString(alertInMillis);
                // ////new alert time is a stirng

                setStringAlertInMillis(sAlertInMillis);

                return newAlertTime;

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Remove hardcode.**
Use

```
final String mins = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
final Pattern minutes = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+) minutes"); 
final Matcher m = minutes.matcher(mins);
String stringMinutes = "0";
if (mins.matches())
{
   stringMinutes = m.group(1);
}  
setAlarm(Integer.parseInt(stringMinutes), stringMinutes);
```

instead of your hardcode

```
String mins = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();  
// your hardcode is here  
setAlarm(Integer.parseInt(stringMinutes), stringMinutes);
```

**2) Use** `DateTimeFormatter` **instead of** `SimpleDateFormatter`
You get java `Date` using `SimpleDateFormatter` and create `DateTime` by this date.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
dt = formatter.parseDateTime(currentDate);
```

**3) Joda works well**
in this code no problem with Joda.

```
String subtractTime(DateTime dt, int minusTime)
```

should works well.
Debug you code, problem is before

```
if(mins.equals("5 minutes")){intmins = 5;}
if(mins.equals("10 minutes")){intmins = 10;}  
//...
```